# Setting a variable in Mutation observer causes Mozilla to crash

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, mozilla, mutation-observers

i setup a mutation observer for a webpage and in it's callback I set a variable to 0, this causes mozilla firefox to hang up. This doesn't happen on chrome by the way:
Javascript.

```
var totalPrice = document.querySelector(".totalPrice");
function mutationCallback(mList, observer){
    var ii = document.querySelector(".item");
    prices = document.querySelectorAll(".priceInfo");
    let tPrice = 0.0;
    prices.forEach((pric, index, array)=>{
        tPrice += parseFloat(pric.textContent) * parseFloat(pric.parentNode.children[1].children[0].value);
    })
    totalPrice.textContent = tPrice.toString();
    console.log(tPrice)
};
```

but once i remove the tPrice = 0 line it runs fine.
I also tried setting `let tPrice = 0.0` before the mutationCallback and it keeps happening.

I saw a reply here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1395767
that suggests using takeRecords(),
but from the mozilla developer website, takeRecords() is used when it's time to stop observing the DOM
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/takeRecords

But, in my case the DOM is to be observed always. How do I fix this please

**ALSO**

Just tried changing the `totalPrice.textContent = tp.toString()` to `totalPrice.id = tp.toString()` and it change it's id just fine without crashing.

Comment: What is `tPrice`?  You did not post its declaration or where its value comes from.

Comment: its just a variable initialization, my original code had ```let tPrice = 0```

Comment: Well all variables should be declared. You have `tPrice` and also `tPrices`; are they supposed to be the same? How exactly is the mutation observer set up in the first place? What element is it "watching"?

Comment: sorry that's a typo, they're all the same. will correct this now